# How to edit path for python in Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, installation-path

This is regarding python installation in Windows 10. I want to edit the environment variable related to python in Windows it would give me the error message **"python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."**

I tried doing this after research.

1. I found that python is installed in this folder. ***C:\Users\visva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32***
2. Then, I tried adding it to user variables for the path.
   [image]

   3. Finally, I saved it.
      But still I get the same error message. I want to know how this path can be modified for python. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Looks like this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: Do you have admin rights to the system?